# difference between 'do too much of something' vs 'do(actual verb) too much'

Tags: sentence-construction

first of all, happy new year everyone!

I would like to know if there's any difference between 'doing too much of something' or 'doing(actual verb) too much'.

for example,
I'm doing too much of travel. vs I'm traveling too much.

Are they exactly same and interchangeable?

Thank you.

Comment: "I'm doing too much travel(ling)" (without _of_).

Answer (score -1):

There could be.

For example:

- You're doing too much cooking.
- You're cooking too much.

The first would be taken to mean that the person is cooking too *often*.

The second could mean that the volume of food that the person is cooking is too great.

Whether there would be a perceived difference would depend on the verb being used, and whether that verb has an idiomatic meaning as a gerund. Context would probably help clear up any confusion.

Also, make sure you choose the appropriate adverb. 'Too much' is for non-countable things; 'too many' for countable. In my example, using 'too often' could clear up some ambiguity. In your example of travel you could perhaps be more specific and say someone is travelling *too often*, or *too far*.